# Integral calculation, solving integral issue

Tags: calculus, integration

Can you guys help me solve this integral?
$$
\int \frac{x^3}{x^4 + 2x^2 - 6}dx
$$

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $x^2 \mapsto u$?

Comment: You may use tools like `Wolfram Alpha` to learn how to solve such on your own :) Here's your query: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+(x%5E3)%2F(x%5E4+%2B+2x%5E2+-+6)
It also has a `Step-by-Step solution` feature: http://i.imgur.com/224DXSl.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $t=x^2+1$ then your integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{t-1}{t^2-7}\,dt=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{tdt}{t^2-7}-
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{t^2-7}.$$
Now
$$\int \frac{tdt}{t^2-7}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(t^2-7)$$
and
$$\int \frac{dt}{t^2-7}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\mbox{arctanh}(t/\sqrt{7})$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$x^4+2x^2-6=(x^2+1)^2-7$$

Let $x^2+1=y\implies2x\ dx=dy$ and $x^2=y-1$

$$\dfrac{2Ay+B}{y^2-7}=A\cdot\dfrac{2y}{y^2-7}+\dfrac B{y^2-7}$$

Use $\dfrac{2a\ du}{u^2-a^2}=\dfrac{u+a-(u-a)}{(u+a)(u-a)}=?$

Answer (score 0):

$$I= \int \frac{x^3}{x^4 + 2x^2 - 6}dx$$

As Arthur suggests, let $u = x^2,du = 2x$

$$I = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{u}{u^2 + 2u - 6}du$$
$$ = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{7}} (\int \frac{u}{u+1-\sqrt{7}}du  -\int \frac{u}{u+1+\sqrt{7}}du  ) $$

Let $z = u+1-\sqrt{7},w = u+1+\sqrt{7}$

$$I = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{7}} (\int \frac{z-1+\sqrt{7}}{z}dz  -\int \frac{w-1-\sqrt{7}}{w}dw) =  \frac{1}{4\sqrt{7}} (z +(\sqrt{7}-1)\ln{z} - w+(1+\sqrt{7}) \ln w)\\ =  \frac{1}{4\sqrt{7}} (u+1-\sqrt{7} +(\sqrt{7}-1)\ln(u+1-\sqrt{7}) - u+1+\sqrt{7} + (1+\sqrt{7})\ln (u+1+\sqrt{7}) ) \\ = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{7}}(2+(\sqrt{7}-1)\ln(u+1-\sqrt{7})+(\sqrt{7}-1)\ln(u+1-\sqrt{7})) = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{7}}(2+(\sqrt{7}-1)\ln(x^2+1-\sqrt{7})+(\sqrt{7}-1)\ln(x^2+1-\sqrt{7}))$$